# How to run windows application on client machine having service pack -1

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I had developed a window application in visual studio 2012 using .net frame work 4.5 
now i want to run that application on client machine having windows xp sp1 
so i m stuck how to proceed ahead
what is requirement of client machine.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Windows XP is dead, so no matter which SP level it has it is an obsolete platform.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.5 does not support XP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You'll need to rebuild with a lower .NET version.